# Существуют ли библиотеки в Python для поиска слов в тексте с учётом замены букв на буквы из других алфавитов?

Tags: python, поиск-библиотек

Существуют ли библиотеки в Python для поиска слов в тексте с учётом замены букв на буквы из других алфавитов, но выглядящие точно так же? Например, 'е' из кириллицы и 'e' из латиницы.

Comment: Вряд ли кто-то будет писать такую библиотеку, Вы можете написать такую функцию в одну или пару строк.

Comment: Возможно эта библиотека - посмотрите transliterate 1.10.2

Comment: Поначалу это только кажется простым, типа замена "е" на "e", однако кроличья нора достаточно быстро становится глубже, с добавлением в микс пробельных символов, Юникода, составных букв ..

Answer (score 0):

Пусть вам нужно найти слово "деньги". Здесь есть одна буква, которая графически выглядит как другая буквы из латиницы:  "е". Пишем простейшее регулярное выражение вроде:

```
r"д[е|e]ньги"
```

И используем это регулярное выражение в функции поиска *re.search(pattern, string)*, которая возвращает первое вхождение подстроки, подходящей под регулярное выражение.